# Why does Angular duplicate the tag even though I used .replaceWith

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Can't explain this behavior - can you help?

I want to create a directive "`iscope`" that provides an isolated scope for the underlying DOM. Such that, for example, I could do the following:

```
<div ng-include="template1" iscope="parentScopeProperty"></div>
```

with the idea that anything within the `ng-include` template will only have access to `parentScopeProperty`.

Here's a snippet of the compile function - the rest is in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dn0xcMeGjyEwelfew185?p=preview)

```
function compile(tElem, tAttr, ngInclude){
  var clone = tElem.clone();
  clone.removeAttr("iscope");
  tElem.replaceWith(clone);

  return function(scope, elem, attr){
    $compile(elem)(scope);
  };
}
```

What ends up happening is that the `<div ng-include>` is generated twice - one for parent scope, one for isolated scope.

Why?

Comment: why don't you just use `templateUrl` of directive instead of `ng-include` ?

Comment: It wasn't meant to be specific to `ng-include`. But now I'm more interested in the behavior that I can't explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ngInclude` is applied twice. When you replace the element in your `compile` function, then `ngInclude` has already been collected and will be applied anyway. Your replacement element also has `ngInclude` so it's applied twice, once for the original node and once for the replacement.

To prevent other directives from being applied after yours, you need to add `terminal: true` to your directive definition object.

Comment: Seems like this is exactly what happens - it works now.